# Removing a bad column from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby-on-rails web application in which I incorrectly added a column to a table.

What I did was in my migration file I put:

```
add_column :my_table, :string, :col_name
```

When of course I should have put:

```
add_column :my_table, :col_name, :string
```

Basically, I switched the column name and type.

It actually did add the column - but without any type.  If I examine the table in the console, it displays a column with the name 'string' but does not list any type.

Now, I can't remove it.  If I do

```
remove_column: my_table, :string
```

I get a nil exception.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Did you do `remove_column :my_table, :string` ? Not sure if its a typo on your post or that's what you did

Comment: @TimMitchell, you've asked 21 questions and haven't accepted a single answer so far. Is there are reason for this? It's considered both polite and helpful to accept answers that have helped address your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the version number and [run the `down` migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations):

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=unique_stamp
```

Also, ensure that you're passing arguments to the function as *symbols*, **not** *strings*:

```
remove_column :my_table, :string
```

Comment: I get the exact same error when I try all of them though, which is the same error I initially got when I tried to remove the column...undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@asset_manager2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:215:in `column'

Comment: You need to symbolize the first argument: `remove_column: :my_table, :string`

Comment: symbolize as in put a : after remove_column?  I get a syntax error.

Comment: You're probably incorrectly entering the colon. Copy and paste the second code snippet from this answer and replace the corresponding line in your migration – it should work.

Comment: Sorry - not trying to be argumentative.  If I cut-and-paste it exactly as you have it - with a colon following the remove_column, I get a syntax error.  If I do it this way - with my original typo corrected - remove_column :my_table, :string   or rename_column, or rollback - I get the nil error.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer. The colon should proceed the names of the two arguments – there should __not__ be a colon directly proceeding `remove_column`. I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: Yeah - I just did a rake db:migrate:reset and started over.  Not sure why none of the other things worked - but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you could try rolling back the migration

```
rake db:rollback
```

see : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Sorry everyone - I had a typo in my original post.  I did in fact try the correct way remove_column :my_table, :string  I still get the error no matter what

Answer (score -1):

You could try renaming the `:string` column?

```
rename_column :my_table, :string, :col_name
```

Comment: I made the same mistake as OP and renaming did not work. Spefically, this: `rename_column :forums, :string, :description`